# Fetching remote objects add "_$$_javassist_x" to type

Tags: java, apache-flex, remoting, blazeds

we have a client/server app (Flex and Java) that uses BlazeDS to do remoting. This allows us to exchange and map types between client and server. For some reason a User type we are retrieving from the server is not sent as "User", but as "User_$$_javassist_x", where x is an integer.

The other types we are sending over all work fine, even the User type used in a different service class.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the User objects were part of a collection that was lazy loaded. After setting the "lazy" attribute to false in the Hibernate mapping, all worked fine.